# ページフッタにあるライセンスに関するヘルプへのリンク先が英語ページのままになっている

Tags: バグ, 延期, ヘルプ

ページのフッタ (右下) に「ユーザーの投稿は CC BY-SA でライセンスされている」ことが表示されており、この文言の一部がヘルプページにリンクしていますが、リンク先が英語版のページに固定されています。

現在のリンク先:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing

しかし該当のヘルプページは各サイト毎に持っており、スタック・オーバーフローにおいても日本語に翻訳済みなので、できればこちらにリンクするようにした方がよいのかなと思いました。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/licensing

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: This has been added to our bug duty rotation. It appears to be this way on all Stack Exchange sites, and will eventually be fixed. / バグデューティローテーションに追加いたしました。全 Stack Exchange サイトでは現在このように英語リンクで固定されておりますが最終的には翻訳リンクへ修正される予定です。